# making drop down menu and tabs dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dynamic, tabs

I have a drop-down menu that displays different tabs on the same cshtml page.

- Each tab displays a list of basketball players.
- Issue: all tabs are displaying the same list. (The age group  7and8). The 9-10 tab and 11-12 tab should contain their own list.
- using: bootstrap for the dropdown tabs and mvc-3

The drop down tab:

```
    <div class="col-9">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-boy" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-boy-tab">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">b-Age</a>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item nav-link" id="bbM7and8-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#bbM7and8" role="tab" aria-controls="bbM7and8" aria-selected="false">7-8</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item nav-link" id="bbM9and10-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#bbM9and10" role="tab" aria-controls="bbM9and10" aria-selected="false">9-10</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item nav-link" id="bbM11and12-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#bbM11and12" role="tab" aria-controls="bbM11and12" aria-selected="false">11-12</a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM7and8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM7and8-tab">
                    @{
                        <div>
                            <partial name="_Displayeach"/>
                        </div>
                    }
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM9and10" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM9and10-tab">{...}</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM11and12" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM11and12-tab">{...}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

_Displayeach partial:

```
@model List<League>

@{    
    if (Model != null && Model.Any())
    {
        foreach(League i in Model)
        {
            foreach (MMLeagueParticipant mmLeagueParticipant in i.allParticipants)
            {
                <p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantFirstName @mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantLastName</p>
            }  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <p>the list is empty</p>
    }
}
```

**What I tried:**

tested to make sure if the tabs were displaying different information: I added the age group numbers for each tab

```
7-8 //how I know each tab is different
@{
    <div>
            <partial name="_Displayeach"/>
    </div>
}
```

**where I believe my issue may be:**

since each tab was different this leads me to believe it may have something to do with my controller and how I pass the list back. I'm fairly new to mvc framework

```
    [HttpGet]
[Route("roster/basketball")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBasketballRoster()
{
    String[] leagueNames = new[]
    {
        "7and8",
        "9and10",
        "11and12"
    };
    List<League> bbLeagues = await db.Leagues
    .Where( l => l.sport == "Basketball" )
    .Where( l => leagueNames.Contains( l.ageRange ) )
    .ToListAsync();

    foreach( League league in bbLeagues )
    {
        List<MMLeagueParticipant> leagueParticipants = await db.Entry( league )
            .Collection( l => l.allParticipants )
            .Query() // <-- This is needed to allow for `Include()`
            .Include( mmp => mmp.child )
            .ToListAsync();
    }
    return View("RosterPageBasketball", bbLeagues);
}

public class RosterPageViewModel
{
    public RosterPageViewModel(IReadOnlyDictionary< String, League > leagues)
    {
        this.Leagues = leagues ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(leagues));
    }
    public IReadOnlyDictionary< String, League > Leagues { get; }
}
```

My league model:

```
int LeagueId { get; set; }
string sport { get; set; }
string gender { get; set; }
string ageRange { get; set; }
​List<MMLeagueParticipant> allParticipants  { get; set; }
```

My ViewModel model:

```
public List<Participant> allParticipants { get; set; }
public ViewModel.Participant participant { get; set; }

public class Participant
{
int ParticipantId { get; set; }
string ParticipantFirstName { get; set; }
string ParticipantLastName { get; set; }
string ParticipantGender { get; set; }
SystemDateTime ParticipantDOB { get; set; }
List<MMLeagueParticipant> all Leagues { get; set; }
}
```

My MMLeagueParticipant middle table for the league model and ViewModel.Participant:

```
int MMLeaugeParticipantId { get; set; }
int ParticipantId { get; set; }
int LeaugeId { get; set; }
leauge sport { get; set; }
ViewModel.Participant child { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to pass a `Dictionary<string, List<League>>` to view,and get list from dictionary to pass it to partial view with `leagueName`.Here is a working demo:

action:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("roster/basketball")]
public IActionResult GetBasketballRoster()
        {
            string[] leagueNames = new[]
            {
                "7and8",
                "9and10",
                "11and12"
            };
            Dictionary<string, List<League>> d = new Dictionary<string, List<League>>();
            foreach (var name in leagueNames)
            {
                List<League> bbLeagues = await db.Leagues
                .Where(l => l.sport == "Basketball")
                .Where(l => l.ageRange==name)
                .ToListAsync();

                foreach (League league in bbLeagues)
                {
                    List<MMLeagueParticipant> leagueParticipants = await db.Entry(league)
                        .Collection(l => l.allParticipants)
                        .Query() // <-- This is needed to allow for `Include()`
                        .Include(mmp => mmp.child)
                        .ToListAsync();
                }
                d.Add(name,bbLeagues);
            }
           
            return View(d);
        }
```

View:

```
@model Dictionary<string, List<League>>
<div class="col-9">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-boy" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-boy-tab">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">b-Age</a>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item nav-link" id="bbM7and8-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#bbM7and8" role="tab" aria-controls="bbM7and8" aria-selected="false">7-8</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item nav-link" id="bbM9and10-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#bbM9and10" role="tab" aria-controls="bbM9and10" aria-selected="false">9-10</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item nav-link" id="bbM11and12-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#bbM11and12" role="tab" aria-controls="bbM11and12" aria-selected="false">11-12</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM7and8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM7and8-tab">
                    <div>
                        @await Html.PartialAsync("_Displayeach", Model["7and8"])
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM9and10" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM9and10-tab">
                    <div>
                        @await Html.PartialAsync("_Displayeach", Model["9and10"])
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM11and12" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM11and12-tab">
                    <div>
                        @await Html.PartialAsync("_Displayeach", Model["11and12"])
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CMD:  "cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'" for each of the @await Html.PartialAsync("_Displayeach", Model["#and#"])

Comment: The key type of dictionary in your project is `string`?The code works in my project.

Comment: I may have had a typo, trying it again and now it doesn't like the view. error in terminal: InvalidOperationException: The view 'GetBasketballRoster' was not found

Comment: The view name in my project is `GetBasketballRoster`.

Comment: i change the the return line to "return View("RosterPageBaseball", d);"     the Error i got : `InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LeagueProject.Models.League]]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LeagueProject.Models.League]'.`

Comment: Please check my answer,I use `@model Dictionary<string, List<League>>` in the  view,not `@model List<League>`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you miss to pass the `legue` to each tab page.
Is not enough to render the partial, you also need to give to each partial a specific model.

1. step is to define a ViewModel for you view

   ```
   public class LeagueViewModel
   {
       //model for each tab
       public List<League> Leagues { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. query data in the controller and return the viewmodel

   ```
   public async Task<LeagueViewModel> Get(YourDbContext db, string[] leagueNames)
       {
           var leagues =await db.Legues
               .Include(x => x.Child)
               .Where(l => l.Sport == "Basketball")
               .Where(l => leagueNames.Contains(l.AgeRange))
               .ToListAsync();

           return new LeagueViewModel
           {
               Leagues = leagues
           };
       }
   ```
3. then in your view, you can loop model.Legues and display the partial

   ```
           foreach (var league in Model.Leagues)
           {
               @await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName", league)
           }
   ```

Comment: I think this might work. I updated my post to show my models. Im not the best at querying in mvc yet.